# WebHID API: disconnect event not triggering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webusb, webhid

I am trying to get a disconnect event from a USB HID device using the WebHID API.

The code:

```
const devices = await navigator.hid.requestDevice({ 
    filters: [{vendorId: 'some_vendor_id'}] ,
});
 const device = devices[0];  


console.log(`HID connected: ${device.productName}`);


if (!device.opened) {
    await device.open(); 
}  

navigator.hid.addEventListener('disconnect', device => { 
    console.log(`HID disconnected: ${device.productName}`); 
});
```

Device connects successfully but after it is turned off or disconnected from computer, `disconnect` event is not triggered.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: [This bug has been fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1082303).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events are not yet implemented. I have filed [an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1082303) to help track this.